# How to do the slide out menu or tab slide out horizontal in sencha touch designer?

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch-2

How to do the slide out menu horizontal in the screens in sencha touch. Is there any field is available in the toolbox of sencha? Otherwise please give me a solution for implementing the tab slide out/slide out menu in sencha touch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Viewport Picker on the right hand side to choose between iPhone, iPad, etc?

We are creating an Ext.Container and using css based webkit transitions for the width and height properties.